# Can I pass a class (BroadcastReceiver) as a method parameter in Android?

Tags: java, android

My Android program has dozens of broadcast receivers, doing all kinds of different things, such that making a generic receiver to handle everything would be impracticable. But I find myself with > 1000 lines of code, doing the same thing over and over again, just setting AlarmManagers pointing to BroadcastReceivers.

Eg:

```
    public void startStatsAlarm() {
        Log.d(TAG, "startStatsAlarm: in start alarm");
        boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 1,
            new Intent(mContext, StatsAlarmReceiver.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

        if(alarmUp){
            Log.d(TAG, "startStatsAlarm: alarm already up, skipping");
            return;
        }

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, StatsAlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent statsIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 1, intent, 0);
        if (alarmMgr != null) {
            alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, statsIntent);
    }
}
```

Is one of many. The only things I need to change are the MINUTE and HOUR, Interval, and BroadcastReceiver.
There must be some way of reusing the same code, rather than having the same thing over and over again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
public void startStatsAlarm(Context mContext, BroadcastReceiver mClass, int hour, int minute) {
        Log.d(TAG, "startStatsAlarm: in start alarm");
        boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 1,
                new Intent(mContext, mClass.getClass()),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
        if (alarmUp) {
            Log.d(TAG, "startStatsAlarm: alarm already up, skipping");
            return;
        }
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, mClass.getClass());
        PendingIntent statsIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 1, intent, 0);
        if (alarmMgr != null) {
            alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, statsIntent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: try to call it like this  `startStatsAlarm(getApplicationContext(), new StatsAlarmReceiver(), 30, 20);`